# SimpleXMLElement and foreach loop issue

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a function that takes two arguments, the first one `$methodName` being a string, and the second one `$parameters` being an array.

```
function constructRequest($methodName, $parameters) {
    // converts atheme parameters to send-able XML
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<methodCall></methodCall>");
    $xml->addChild("methodName", $methodName);
    $params = $xml->addChild("params");
    foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
        $param = $xml->params->addChild("param");
        $value = $xml->params->param->addChild("value");
        $param = $xml->params->param->value->addChild("string", $parameter);
    }

    return $xml->asXML();

}
```

Here's my index.php

```
<?php

include("libatheme.php");

$test = new Atheme("nightcoast.net");
echo $test->constructRequest("atheme.login", array("yonky", "donkey", "keyhole"));
header("Content-type: text/xml");

?>
```

What this should produce is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>atheme.login</methodName>
    <params>
        <param><value><string>yonky</string></value></param>
        <param><value><string>donkey</string></value></param>
        <param><value><string>keyhole</string></value></param>
</methodCall>
```

however it produces:

```
<methodCall>
<methodName>atheme.login</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<string>yonky</string>
<string>donkey</string>
<string>keyhole</string>
</value>
<value/>
<value/>
</param>
<param/>
<param/>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always referencing the same `param` and the same `value` when you do these:

```
$xml->params->param
```

and

```
$param = $xml->params->param->value
```

---

What you really want to do is this:

```
$params = $xml->addChild("params");
foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    $param = $params->addChild("param");
    $value = $param->addChild("value");
    $value->addChild("string", $parameter);
}
```

Comment: So, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: See the second half of the answer.